# Why are the eigenfunctions linear independent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

At a Sturm-Liouville problem how do we know that the two eigenfunctions that we have found are linear independent??

For example we have the following problem :

$$X''+\lambda X=0 \\ X(0)=X(2\pi) \\ X'(0)=X^\circ(2\pi)$$

We find that for $\lambda=k^2>0$ we have $X(x)=c_1\cos (kx)+c_2\sin (kx)$.

We have two linear independent eigenfunctions $\cos (kx), \sin (kx)$.

How do we know these two eigenfunctions are linear independent??

Comment: Well, any two functions are either linearly independent or scalar multiples of each other. (The same can't be said for more than two functions.)

Comment: @whacka : Not quite.  If one of them is the zero function, then the other is not a scalar multiple of it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that that $\{v_j\}$ are eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}$ and that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^na_jv_j=0\tag{1}
$$
For any $k$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=T^k\sum_{j=1}^na_jv_j\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\lambda_j^kv_j\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
For $0\le k\le n-1$, $(2)$ can be rewritten as
$$
0=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\lambda_3&\cdots&\lambda_n\\
\lambda_1^2&\lambda_2^2&\lambda_3^2&\cdots&\lambda_n^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\lambda_1^{n-1}&\lambda_2^{n-1}&\lambda_3^{n-1}&\cdots&\lambda_n^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1v_1\\a_2v_2\\a_3v_3\\\vdots\\a_nv_n
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
$$
Since the $\lambda_j$ are distinct and the square matrix in $(3)$ is a [Vandermonde Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), we know its determinant is
$$
\prod_{i\lt j}(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)\ne0\tag{4}
$$
Thus, each $a_j=0$ and therefore the eigenvectors are independent.

Comment: One should be able to show this without using self-adjointness. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I could not think of a way, but I will continue to think on it.

Comment: I added at my initial post a specific example...could you take a look at it??

Comment: @MaryStar: One way to show that $\cos(kx)$ and $\sin(kx)$ are linearly independent is by orthogonality. $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(kx)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

Comment: Do we take always the integral over the interval $[0,2\pi]$ to check if two eigenfunctions are linearly independent?? @robjohn

Comment: @MaryStar: No. It is just one way. What we need to show is that if $a\sin(kx)+b\cos(kx)=0$, then $a=b=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Doh! I simply had to write down the equations and follow my nose. This proof does not rely on much of anything, now.